# What is definition of "excessive correlation" is Michael Persinger using?

Tags: experimental-psychology

I'm trying to parse the significance of Michael Persinger's work. From what I can understand, he uses toroids to create magnetic fields which can [change the PH of spring water](https://www.infona.pl/resource/bwmeta1.element.baztech-237ff459-eb61-4787-bf1d-287e3573db2d) and [change photon emission in brain tissue](http://file.scirp.org/Html/17181.html). He then applies this to [two human brains separated by great distances](http://jcer.com/index.php/jcj/article/view/493).

Are his results significant? If so, what predictions are they making? All I can make out from these papers is that when brains are exposed to similar to conditions they exhibit similar brain waves. Why don't they compare to a baseline of those not exposed to these magnetic signals? And why do they only show the correlation between paired individuals, instead of showing correlation between paired and non-paired individuals?

Comment: What a weird paper :P

Comment: @mrt it's from my home town... When I tried to bring up my work, I kept being pointed to this dude, so I thought I would get a good understanding of what he's saying so I can predict the type of conversations I would be having.